# Proper scaling factor for depth/velocity perception

Tags: graphics, 3d, game-engine, distance, scaling

I'm programming my first 3d game engine (in C, no graphics libraries or OpenGL) and encountering a bunch of new concepts.  I've wrestled through matrices, rotation, translation, and scaling.  I'm sure plenty of my concepts are still off.

I know that to convey depth perception (and speed), I need to scale objects based on their distance to the "camera".  If I had to guess I'd say an object doubles in perceived size every time distance halves, but that's just a guess -- can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between distance and apparent height of objects is an inverse-linear function:

[image]

where h is the apparent height, d is the distance of the object, and a is the actual size of the object.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(visual)

Comment: Thanks!  That put me on the right track.  Other people looking to work on stuff like this might want to search for "Angular Size", "Visual Angle", and "object distance vs image size"